# Is there any way to reflect Javascript changes in a C# application?

Tags: c#, javascript, d3.js, spotfire

I'm pretty sure I know the answer to this, but currently, I am importing D3 into an embedded browser inside the data visualization program called Spotfire. Ideally, I would like to import this: 
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/iris-splom.html

into an embedded browser in Spotfire. I've already imported a gauge visualization, which looks at Spotfire's API to get the data values, then writes them to an HTML/Javascript file including D3, and then loads the file in the embedded browser, which causes the gauge to move.

The issue comes here: In the scatterplot matrix in D3, you can make a box around the points and select them. I would like to reflect these changes in Spotfire, by looking at the slected values and then setting them as marked using Spotfire's C# API.

Is this possible? I'm finding it difficult to visualize how Javascript could change C#'s content. The only way I can imagine would be if I invoked a function every X amount of time that parsed through the Javascript to check for any highlighted values by calling a setInterval which returned the selected values in D3 every X amount of time.

Comment: Yes there are two ways: form submit and Ajax.

Comment: What version of Spotfire are you using? Are you using the SDK or IronPython? I am able to import other javascript libraries via ironPython, but for some reason I find it difficult to get this d3.js to work within a textarea. 

If you are using the SDK and you are using your own Browser Control, [there are ways to get access the DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290341(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I'm using Spotfire version 6.0' SDK. Javascript won't work within the text area, as it lacks capabilities for certain graphical elements as well as scripts. Because System.Windows.Forms uses some old version of IE, I just hope that the browser control I am using (Awesomium) supports this HTML grabbing functionality as well.

I've also been looking through AJAX documentation, but it is a LOT to take in. I wouldn't know how to structure my program in a way that would let me use it.